# Must onCreateOptionsMenu become implemented of each activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

When I have an app with multiple activities and like to have an options-menu all-over: **Do I have to override the onCreateOptionsMenu-method in each activity?**
Or can that become centralized?

Comment: You do not have to override that in one single activity.

Comment: If I haven't the method within a specific activity, then the options-menu won't appear.

Comment: I think i made a stupid comment. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent that boilerplate code creating a common Activity which all of your Activities inherit.

```
abstract class CommonSaveActivity : Activity() {
    @CallSuper
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.common_save_action_menu, menu)
        return true
    }

    @CallSuper
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.saveAction -> {
                // TODO: handle common save action
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}

class ActivityA : CommonSaveActivity()

class ActivityB : CommonSaveActivity()

class ActivityC : CommonSaveActivity() {
    // You can have the common save menu AND your 
    // activity specific menu at the same time in UI.
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // NOTE: if you call super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu) AFTER 
        // menuInflater.infalte(..) line, then the order of menu 
        // items will be different.
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_c_menu, menu)
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Great. Exactly what I was looking for. The only thing I had to changed was, that I had to inherit the CommonSaveActivity-class from AppCompatActivity. Instead of Activity. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, I kind of guessed that, but I just gave the simplest example so you could get the idea :)